# Autoajustar ancho de columnas Java Netbeans

Tags: java, jtable, netbeans-11.3

¡Hola¡ Alguien me podría ayudar necesito que las columnas de mi jtable se ajusten automáticamente al texto de las celdas ya que unas tienen poco texto y otras mucho mas.

¡Gracias¡

Este es mi jtable

[image: Este es mi jtable]

Este es mi código

```js
    public void vertransportadores() {
        String sql, datos[] = new String[6];
        String titulos[] = {"ID", "NOMBRES", "APELLIDOS", "TELEFONO", "DNI", "RUTA"};
        DefaultTableModel mimodelo = new DefaultTableModel(null, titulos);
        sql = "select * from transportadores";

        try {
            con = conex.getConnection();
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                datos[0] = rs.getString("idtransportador");
                datos[1] = rs.getString("nombres");
                datos[2] = rs.getString("apellidos");
                datos[3] = rs.getString("telefono");
                datos[4] = rs.getString("dni");
                datos[5] = rs.getString("ruta");
                mimodelo.addRow(datos);

            }

            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }

    }
```